# Memcached Gui Manager for VPS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

I am looking for GUI interface for my web application to see the stats for the memcached. How much memcached is used, How much is free.

It will be great if it can show keys stored in memcache and show the growth of the memcache consumed in form of charts etc

I came to know about [one](https://github.com/thiagofm/memcached-manager), Buts its in very early development.

Any suggestions?

**Good to have:**

- It will be great if it integrates smoothly with my rails application.
- A separate sub-domain will work.
- PHP, Python or anything other solution will work

On Heroku I have an another application running and [memcache](https://www.memcachier.com) addon provides good enough interface for it. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, you can't know the list of keys stored in a memcached server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are numerous tools doing what you want; a very basic one (single PHP file) is [MemachedGUI](https://github.com/mailopl/memcached-gui); a more complex one is [phpMemcachedAdmin](http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/) .

There isn't "one memcached GUI to rule them all"; however, the 2 projects cited above being open source, you should be able to customize them fairly easily to do your bidding (especially with regards to graph etc.).

Do keep in mind that there isn't a way to reliably and comprehensively view all the keys stored in memcached; tools that do display that are using [this trick](http://www.darkcoding.net/software/memcached-list-all-keys/), which is very limited.